# how can i proof $3^n$ has a greater growth than $n2^n$?

Tags: asymptotics

i want to prove that $3^n$ has a greater growth than $n2^n$ or $3^n = O(n2^n)$. but how can i do it mathematically? by induction or contradiction or other ways of proof.

Comment: Use definition?

Comment: yes, every way which is mathematically true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be divide both sides by $2^n$ to get $n$ and $(1.5)^n$. You can simply take a limit of $l  i  m_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1.5)^n}{n} = \infty$ To show that $(1.5)^n$ grows larger. This limit holds for any number larger than 1.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer! Note that we have [collected a number of reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) that provide vetted answers that cover many exercise problems, including this one. Posting answers to every similat question is probably a waste of time.

Comment: Oh sorry. Did not think of referencing a more general question initially. Thank you for pointing that out. Should this answer be erased?

Comment: i liked to prove it by contradiction or induction, not only the common ways. is that against of rules?